# Are there generics with type parameters (generics with generics)?

Tags: java, generics, higher-kinded-types

I need to define a generic Bus interface that can either be a `CommandBus` or `QueryBus`.

```
public interface Bus {

    <T> T execute(BusRequest<T> request);

}

public interface BusRequest<T> {
}
```

The above example works, but I'll want to replace `BusRequest` by another generic that will extend `BusRequest`, so that you could do the following:

```
public interface CommandBus extends Bus<Command> {

    // Inherited method would turn into something like
    // <T> T execute(Command<T> cmd);

}

public interface Command<T> extends BusRequest<T> {
}
```

How would I define the `Bus` interface to do that? Is it possible in Java?

I have tried:

```
public interface Bus<R extends BusRequest> {

    <T> T execute(R<T> request);

}
```

However it says:

> Type 'R' does not have type parameters

Comment: Did you mean to put these types on the interface (`interface Bus<RequestType, ResponseType>`) ?

Comment: No, they should remain method generics. I'll want to call the method with different request/response types.

Comment: What you're describing is called an existential type. Java's type system is not that powerful. But you could create an interface like `Request<ResponseT>` and use something like `public <ResponseT, RequestT extends Request<ResponseT> ResponseT execute(RequestT request)`.

Comment: @DanielPryden That's almost it! However I don't want `RequestT` to be a method generic, but rather a class generic. When I put it into the class's generic list it still says "can not resolve symbol '`ResponseT`'". Any ideas?

Comment: If `Request` is parameterized by `Response`, you can't parameterize anything by a specific `Request` while keeping the `Response` type free. In Haskell you could define a "forall" type, but Java has no equivalent to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't express this type relationship in a way the Java compiler will understand. But you could get a similar effect by making `BusRequest` types know about the type of `Bus` they're supposed to be used with, and by making `Bus` know what type of Bus it is.

For example:

```
// B is the type of the Bus subclass
public interface Bus<B extends Bus<B>> {
    // R is the response type, and Q is the request type
    <R, Q extends BusRequest<R, B>> R execute(Q request);
}

// a request is parameterized by R, the response type, and B, the bus type
public interface BusRequest<R, B extends Bus<B>> {}

// A CommandBus is a Bus for CommandBusRequests
public static class CommandBus implements Bus<CommandBus> {
    @Override
    public <R, Q extends BusRequest<R, CommandBus>> R execute(Q request) {
        System.out.println("Got request of type: " + request.getClass());
        return null;
    }
}

public interface CommandBusRequest<T> extends BusRequest<T, CommandBus> {}

// StringCommandBusRequest is a BusRequest for a CommandBus that requests
// a response of type String
public static class StringCommandBusRequest
        implements CommandBusRequest<String> {}
```

These types all compile and type check, and the result looks like what I think you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StringCommandBusRequest request = new StringCommandBusRequest();
    Bus<CommandBus> bus = new CommandBus();
    String result = bus.execute(request);
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/U1TLXr

To be more useful, however, you'll probably need some bus-specific payload information in each request object. As this stands, each request type is tied to a bus type, but the bus isn't able to extract bus-specific data from the request object, because for example there could be more than one class that implements `BusRequest<?, CommandBus>`.

To solve this, we just need to introduce another(!) type parameter to keep track of the payload type. For example:

```
public interface Bus<P, B extends Bus<P, B>> {
    <R, Q extends BusRequest<R, P, B>> R execute(Q request);
}

public interface BusRequest<R, P, B extends Bus<P, B>> {
    P getPayload();
}

public static class CommandBus
        implements Bus<CommandBusRequestPayload, CommandBus> {
    @Override
    public <R, Q extends BusRequest<R, CommandBusRequestPayload, CommandBus>>
        R execute(Q request) {
            CommandBusRequestPayload payload = request.getPayload();
            System.out.println("Got payload: " + payload);
            return null;
    }
}

public static abstract class CommandBusRequest<T>
        implements BusRequest<T, CommandBusRequestPayload, CommandBus> {
    @Override
    public CommandBusRequestPayload getPayload() {
        return new CommandBusRequestPayload();
    }
}

public static class CommandBusRequestPayload {}

public static class StringCommandBusRequest
        extends CommandBusRequest<String> {}
```

Demo with payload: https://ideone.com/2aUwMW

Comment: This looks awesome, you're a genius. I'll have to try that right away - can I also make `CommandBus` accept only `CommandBusRequests`?

Comment: @DoubleM: No, unfortunately, since then it would no longer successfully be a subtype of `Bus<CommandBus>`. There could be arbitrarily many types that implement `BusRequest<T, CommandBus>` and you need to accept any of them. In practice, especially if you only expect there to only be one such type, you could do a cast inside the implementation of `execute`.

Comment: However each request type would be bound to a bus type, right? Therefore I could not pass a request to a `CommandBus` that was designated to a `CommandBus` in the first place.

Comment: @DoubleM: Yes. See my edit where I expanded to show how to pass bus-specific request data to the bus implementation.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

A [Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory))?

No. You'll need Scala (or Haskell) for that.

Comment: I have refined my question. Does your answer still apply?