# How to refer to generic paramenter's own parameters, such as T in T2<T>?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Consider following interface:

```
class SomeParamClass<T> {
    public T getT() {return null;}
}
class GetThing<T, TSomeImpl extends SomeParamClass<T>> {
    TSomeImpl thingcreator;
    GetThing(TSomeImpl thingcreator) {
        this.thingcreator = thingcreator;
    }
    T getThing() {
        return thingcreator.get(offset);
    }
    TSomeImpl getOrigClass() {
        return thingcreator;
    }
}
```

This is just an example of a problem that I encountered few times already.

In this example, type `T` is directly bound to parameter `TSomeImpl`. If you create it like this:

```
new GetThing<String,TSomeImpl<String>>(new TSomeImpl<String>())
```

The parameter `String` is repeated unnecessarily. It is **redundant**, but Java seems to require it in this case.

Is there a way to use generic parameters inner parameter as a type?

I made up this syntax, is there a syntax that actually works for this?

```
// Pseudocode on refering to generic parameter's parameters
class GetThing<TSomeImpl extends SomeParamClass<T>, TSomeImpl::<T>> {
    TSomeImpl thingcreator;
    GetThing(TSomeImpl thingcreator) {
        this.thingcreator = thingcreator;
    }
    TSomeImpl::<T> getThing() {
        return thingcreator.get(offset);
    }
    TSomeImpl getOrigClass() {
        return thingcreator;
    }
}
```

That would be than used just as:

```
GetThing<TSomeImpl<String>>
```

No other parameters are necessary.

**To clarify:** How can I re-write the original class so that it only has one generic argument, `List<T>` and the `T` argument is inferred, since it is unambiguously known from `List<T>`.

Comment: you want to be able to call something like this: `new GetListEntry<String,ArrayList<>>(new ArrayList<>)` ?

Comment: whats the question exactly? not yet clear IMHO .... and what is `TList::<T>`??

Comment: Is there a problem with using `GetListEntry<String,ArrayList<String>> le = new GetListEntry<> (new ArrayList<>());`?

Comment: @Eran It adds redundant code to any definition or inheritance. I'm aware of both possible syntaxes mentioned here in comments, but they are not applicable everywhere.

Comment: I'm not casting a close quote because I'm not sure I want to use my dupehammer on this, but this question, if not an exact duplicate, is at least very closely related: [Are there generics with type parameters (generics with generics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915280/are-there-generics-with-type-parameters-generics-with-generics/52916011)

Comment: I think bottom line is with your current design if you keep `TSomeImpl` as a generic argument you cannot escape providing both arguments when you define the variable. If you don’t need to know the exact type of `TSomeImpl` returned from getOrigClass at _compile_ time the just get rid of the argument and make your getOrigClass() method return `SomeClass<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

what about this

```
interface SomeType<T> {
    T getT();
}

class SomeParamClass<T> implements SomeType<T> {
    public T getT() {return null;}
}

class GetThing<T> {
    SomeType<T> thingcreator;
    GetThing(SomeType<T> thingcreator) {
        this.thingcreator = thingcreator;
    }
    T getThing() {
        return thingcreator.getT();
    }
    SomeType<T> getOrigClass() {
        return thingcreator;
    }
}
```

you can use it like this

```
new GetThing<String>(new SomeParamClass<>());
```

Comment: This also hides the type of `SomeParamClass`.

Comment: @TomášZato The type of `SomeParamClass` is `SomeType` and it is not hidden. I don't understand why do you need the implementation class instead of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to use `TList` as some kind of alias. That's not what generics are for.

Generic type parameters are just that: parameters. There's no way to hide a parameter. They must be explicit.

What's wrong with this? Why doesn't it satisfy your requirements?

```
class GetListEntry<T>
{
    List<T> list;
    GetListEntry(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    T getValueAt(int offset) {
        return list.get(offset);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a major difference between this syntax and the syntax I used. In your version, the specific type of the `List` is no longer visible. This gets relevant in cases where the original type is to be accessed.

Comment: @TomášZato Why would any of your code ever care about which specific list implementation is being used? That sounds 100% like bad design. Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: I used list in my example only as that, an example. The alternative would including more classes in my question, and more text, making it harder to understand.

Comment: @TomášZato easier to understand... at the expense of accuracy... uhhh...

Comment: The principle is the same regardless of whether or not its a list, anyway. If you care about the concrete type, your design is wrong. The problems you are having with generics are a result of your design being wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand the problem but what is TList for? Looks like a redundant definition. Wouldn't something like this work:

```
public class ListOfSomething<T> {

private List<T> things;

public ListOfSomething(List<T> things) {
    super();
    this.things = things;
}

T getValueAt(int offset) {
    return this.things.get(offset);
}
```

}

Comment: Sometimes you need to access the original type of the `List`.  Consider an example where the generic parameter is not a list at all, but some custom super interface with quite different implementations.

Comment: Well Imo, even if you told in another comment that it would take more code, you should come up with a clearer example. Because this one doesn't really explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You're right, but I'm confused why would everyone try to solve a question that is posed as generic, abstract problem by a solution that only solves it for the example that is given, instead of focusing on the generic solution (assuming one exists).

Comment: @TomášZato If *everyone* answers your question a certain way, it's probably a good idea to assume that your question is the problem, not everyone answering it.

Answer (score 0):

I would referr to Michaels answer. There does not seem to be an apparent reason for you to mask your list like that. However, if you really want to do it this way, I belive you can do it by just leaving out the generic parameters in your variable declaration. The only place you need to specify this, is the parameters of the constructor. So, just using

```
GetListEntry test = new GetListEntry(new ArrayList<String>());
```

should work fine.

You can try my test code on [this java online compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler). Thats where I tried it and it works fine.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        stringList.add("1");
        stringList.add("2");
        stringList.add("3");

        GetListEntry test = new GetListEntry(stringList);

        for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            System.out.println(test.getValueAt(i));

    }

    static class GetListEntry<T, TList extends List<T>> {
        TList list;
        GetListEntry(TList list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
        T getValueAt(int offset) {
            return list.get(offset);
        }
    }
}
```

As you said, the information is redundant. So, the needed information is taken from where its already mentioned. Namely, the ArrayList's generic Type.