# Can I avoid explicit cast with "generics" or better "design patterns"?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I have an interface

```
public interface Query {

}
```

and its implementation:

```
public class UserQuery implements Query {
// specific properties to query a user
}
```

and another interface

```
public interface Queries{

protected void runQuery(Query q);
}
```

and its implementation which make use of it:

```
public UserQueries extends Queries{

@Override
protected void runQuery(Query q){

// can I avoid this explicit cast with generic type parameters or other design patterns?
// for example Query<UserQuery> ?
var uq = (UserQuery) q;
..

}
```

}

All works, however, how can I avoid the cast in `runQuery(Query q)` (Maybe with `runQuery(Query<T> q)`)?

Imagine a set of different implementation of `Query` (`UserQuery`, `StoreQuery`, `BalanceQuery`, etc - with the solution above, I have to make an explict cast in every overriding method which is a little awkward.

**Are there any better design-pattern for such uses cases as above?**

Comment: Why are you casting `q` to `UserQuery`?

Comment: @rgettman because I want to access the properties from UserQuery.

Comment: In the interface `Query`, you must have a common method, like `run`, that all classes must implement. Then, `Queries` will call `run` and the implementation must take care of everything. If you are doing casts, you don't need an interface or should create a specific implementation of `Queries` to run only `UserQuery`

Comment: Put another way: If `Queries` can handle a plain `Query`, but `UserQueries` cannot handle a plain `Query`, then `UserQueries` should not be a sub-type of `Queries`, by the Liskov Substitution Principle. (LSP basically says that a subtype should be able to do everything its supertype does, plus something more.)

Comment: @DanielPryden are there any better solutions/design patterns for such use case?

Comment: @Sigrist no, the "run"-method is only within `Queries`-Interface. The `Query`-Interface is an empty interface (decorator pattern?)..

Comment: So the better choice is to make Queries a generic interface, like the accepted answer

Comment: @nimo23: If there is nothing meaningful you can do with a `Query` (or a `Queries` object) without knowing the type, then polymorphism isn't helping you any here. Simply drop the `Query` interface and have the various `Query` objects inherit from `Object` directly.

Comment: @DanielPryden However, Query is semantically better than Object. Besides, maybe in future `Query` can have methods..

Comment: @nimo23: It's hard to say for sure without knowing more of the semantics of these objects, but [this answer I wrote for another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916011/128397) might be an option for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make `Queries` a generic interface:

```
public interface Queries<Q extends Query> {

    protected void runQuery(Q q);
}
```

Then, `UserQueries` can use a specific type `Query`:

```
public class UserQueries implements Queries<UserQuery> {

    @Override
    protected void runQuery(UserQuery q) {
        // q is a UserQuery, no need to cast anything...
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect:) Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that, if you go this route, you won't be able to use a raw `Queries` object unless you know what its type parameter is (which is tantamount to knowing the exact subtype in this scheme). If you only have a `Queries<?>`, the only value you can legally pass into `runQuery` is `null`.

Comment: @DanielPryden good point. However, are there any better solutions/design patterns for such use case?

Comment: @DanielPryden here right, you can only pass `null`, but in general you can pass `Queries<?>` to a generic method accepting `Queries<T>`, thus _read_ a `T` from it and theoretically add (if such an operation would be exposed by `Queries`) that instance again; thus duplicate that element.